# display hover text when hovering on labels too

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am making a dashboard using dash. The charts show hovertext when hovering on the points in the scatter plot. I want to see the same hovertext when the cursor is hovered on labels of points. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only objects that can trigger hover text are the actual data points. So you will have to maneuver the point/label such that the your mouse would be hovering over the point and the label simultaneously, but it would still be the point that was triggering the hover text to appear.

https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/